# Extjs LabelAlign 'top' click issue

Tags: extjs, label, focus

We have ExtJs fields in which LabelAlign is configured as 'top', but when we click on label it focusses the field, this creates problem if the field is checkbox, as on click of checkbox label it checks/unchecks the checkbox field. I have searched for some configs to disable the same , but couldn't find out. Later i used pointer-events:none CSS property on labels but not sure it will be correct solution. please guide.

[Fiddle Example illustrating the above issue](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1ung)

Comment: Using pointer-events may not work correctly on older browsers including IE prior to version 11. [more info here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/pointer-events/)

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent the click on the label from affecting the checkbox by removing the `for` attribute from the label.  This will break the association between the label and the checkbox.  To do this in ExtJS:

```
Ext.query('label[id^=checkbox]').forEach(function (item) {
    item.removeAttribute('for');
});
```

This will find all of the labels for checkboxes and remove the `for` attribute so the label is no longer associated with the checkbox.

If you want to implement this for all fields, not just checkboxes, change it to search for all labels:

```
Ext.query('label').forEach(function (item) {
    item.removeAttribute('for');
});
```

This code should be executed after your form is created.

See updated fiddle [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1upm).

Answer (score 0):

There is no as such solution as far as i know for that because it will happen in every field not only in checkbox but there is a workaround that, you can add two xtypes as label and field needed and arrange them in vbox layout and give that label a 'html' config as that fieldlabel of the next field.

For e.g,

```
{
xtype:'container',
layout:{
type:'vbox'
},
items:[
{
xtype:'label',
html:'Email Address'
},
{
xtype:'checkboxfield',
name: 'email'
}
]
}
```

With this the container that will be made by extjs for checkboxfield will be different for label and field so when you click on label that's a different control for it and hence won't check the checkboxfield.

Comment: Yes ,I also have tried the same , but since the UI fields are large in number in our app, it creates more code lines and components  :(